# deploy mvc to iis 7 - list of directories and files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7

I have developed a standard MVC application with MVC 3.5, and I was trying to get it in IIS to let me navigate through the localhost. Well, I published that project in the localhost path but when I type that in the browser, well... It didn't show me the site, but a list of files and directory founded in the localhost.

What should I do? IIS is full installed, and the "DefaultAppPool" is set up with Framework 4.0 and ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Thanks in advance to everybody.

Problem solved:
I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, and I have installed aspnet_regiis 32 bit version. That was a mess that keep me busy for 3 days, damn it!
By the way now it works successful, and I'm finally happy to type some code instead of reading forum. 
That's all, thanks everybody.

Comment: How did you publish it? Through Visual Studio? Did you use a file system path or a url to publish?

Comment: I publish that through VS2010. It deploy the project in the localhost folder, adding a new directory as I wish.
Edit: Forgot to reply the second question: I use the Web Deploy method to publish.

Comment: Are you publishing to a url or file path? If you publish to a url, it _should_ create the virtual directory for you, a file path will not.

Comment: Url. I attach an image of what I'm looking at
http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/7476/vediamoselouppo.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your deploy location is not configured as an application in IIS. Try [these instructions](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/18/visual-studio-2010-web-application-packaging-and-publishing.aspx), but tick the *Mark as IIS application on destination* box.

Or you could open up [IIS Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4b3aded-09fe-43c6-9634-d878d23940eb) and make your location an application there.

Comment: The first advice is the path that I follow, the same of how I did it, and doesn't work. Obiously I did a new project and follow each step from the guide: no way...

I tryied the second step following the guide, but that doesn't work too. 

Is my pc rebelling to me?

Comment: I missed a step on the second advice: "Optionally, click Test Settings to verify the settings that you specified for the application".
While testing that it give me an error telling that the file path is wrong, while it is the right one (documents/Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication6). I don't understand what is happening :V

Answer (score 5):

Try adding in web.config <runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> in section system.webServer.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: this worked for me. can anyone explain for what purpose we need to use this?